# Change text and color of dynamically created button

Tags: javascript

I have a red button that is dynamically created and put into a li along with some user input. Looks like this

[image: this]

If the user clicks on the red button, the li element is prepended to another li like this

[image: this]

I want to be able to change the button from red to green and change the text from 'started' to 'unmark' when it moves to the second li and then back to red with the right text if that button is clicked again to move it back.

I'm not quite sure where to write the function to do this? Should I do this outside of my previous written functions or within each relevant ones? And if so, what would it look like because my button only has an id and no value, which is the method I've seen all over stackoverflow.

Thank you!

**Edit: Code Snippet** It looks like it's not showing the second column (configurations are all off)... does it work on other's people laptops?

```js
// Dynamically creates a new li element with 'started' button after user puts in text and clicks a button similar to 'submit'
$(document).ready(
  $("#new-item").on('click', function() {
    // once the document loads, create new item with this function
    var text = $('#task').val();
    if (text != '') {
      $('#todo-list').prepend("<li class='addedTask'> <button id='started' value='on'>Started</button>" + text + '</li>');
    }

  })
);

// Clicking on the 'started' button will move the task from 'todo-list' to 'doing-list'
$("#todo-list").on('click', "button", function() {

  var completedItem = $(this).parent();
  $('#doing-list').prepend($(completedItem));
});

// Clicking on the 'unmark' button will moe the task back from 'doing-list' to 'todo-list'
$("#doing-list").on('click', "button", function() {
    var completedItem = $(this).parent();
    $('#todo-list').prepend($(completedItem));
});
```

```css
header {
 background-color: #026aa7;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 8px;
}

header a {
 height: 30px;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(https://a.trellocdn.com/dist/images/header-logo-2x.01ef898811a879595cea.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 background-size: 80px 30px;
}

body {
 background-color: #0078c0;
 margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*Add a card button*/
#new-item {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/*User input*/
#task {
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.column {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    min-height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 75px;
    right: 287px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.column h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #393939;
    margin: 5px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

li.addedTask {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 83%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/*Cards in the todo list*/
#started {
    float: left;
    background-color: #E65C5C;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<head>

    <title> HW03 Javascript and jQuery </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="https://trello.com"></a>
        </header>

        <section>
            <!-- create input tag for user input -->
            <input type="text" id="task">


            <!-- button takes input and adds a new element with content to 'list_do' -->
            <button id="new-item"> Add a card </button>


            <!-- ability to move items between list_todo and list_doing -->
            <div class="column" id="to-do">
                <h1> To Do </h1>
                <li id="todo-list"></li>
            </div>

            <div class="column" id="doing">
                <h1> Doing </h1>
                <li id="doing-list"></li>
            </div>

        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/main.js"> </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you know you can post html/js/css examples embedded in the Stack Overflow question? - Makes it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I think you should bind the function to the Task rather than the list itself.

Comment: why dont you play with css classes for this? you can change the classes easily

Comment: Ok added. Also I realize that you can make it full page which shows both columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```js
// Dynamically creates a new li element with 'started' button after user puts in text and clicks a button similar to 'submit'
$(document).ready(
  $("#new-item").on('click', function() {
    // once the document loads, create new item with this function
    var text = $('#task').val();
    if (text != '') {
      $('#todo-list').prepend("<li class='addedTask unmark'> <button id='started' value='on'>Started</button>" + text + '</li>');
    }

  })
);

// Clicking on the 'started' button will move the task from 'todo-list' to 'doing-list'
$("#todo-list").on('click', "button", function() {

  var completedItem = $(this).parent();
  change(completedItem, true);
  $('#doing-list').prepend($(completedItem));
});

// Clicking on the 'unmark' button will moe the task back from 'doing-list' to 'todo-list'
$("#doing-list").on('click', "button", function() {
    var completedItem = $(this).parent();
    change(completedItem, false);
    $('#todo-list').prepend($(completedItem));
});
function change(selector, isMarked) {
    if(isMarked) {
        $(selector).removeClass('unmark');
        $(selector).addClass('mark');
    } else {
        $(selector).removeClass('mark');
        $(selector).addClass('unmark');
    }
}
```

```css
header {
 background-color: #026aa7;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 8px;
}

header a {
 height: 30px;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(https://a.trellocdn.com/dist/images/header-logo-2x.01ef898811a879595cea.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 background-size: 80px 30px;
}

body {
 background-color: #0078c0;
 margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*Add a card button*/
#new-item {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/*User input*/
#task {
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.column {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    min-height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 75px;
    right: 287px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.column h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #393939;
    margin: 5px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

li.addedTask {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 83%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/*Cards in the todo list*/
#started {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
}
.mark button {
  background-color: green;
}
.unmark button {
  background-color: #E65C5C;
}
```

```html
<head>

    <title> HW03 Javascript and jQuery </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="https://trello.com"></a>
        </header>

        <section>
            <!-- create input tag for user input -->
            <input type="text" id="task">


            <!-- button takes input and adds a new element with content to 'list_do' -->
            <button id="new-item"> Add a card </button>


            <!-- ability to move items between list_todo and list_doing -->
            <div class="column" id="to-do">
                <h1> To Do </h1>
                <li id="todo-list"></li>
            </div>

            <div class="column" id="doing">
                <h1> Doing </h1>
                <li id="doing-list"></li>
            </div>

        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/main.js"> </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to work on my end. Can I see a snippet of this to see what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Actually, i think this was meant to be more of an example? So I would need to define the isMarked function? Or can just create a boolean statement to check if it is marked or not, right?

Comment: I'll put a example here just answer in a few seconds :D

Comment: just missed a `button` word in css after `mark` and `unmark` style

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! Quick follow up, what is the purpose of the isMarked parameter of the change function? I previously assumed it was another function but I think it's just a parameter into the change function but I don't see it defined or instantiated anywhere?

Comment: it is used inside of `change` function itself for `if` condition @jyp95

Comment: Hmm.. but you didn't set isMarked to any boolean so what is referring to when you say if (isMarked)?